# Problem creating font uvblo

Tags: fonts

I'm trying to compile from a template and get the following error concerning font uvblo, even though the template provides a file UVBLO.tvm. I'm using TeXStudio 2.5.2 and MiKTeX 2.9, and have it configured to install missing packages on the fly.

Initially, I got the following error on compilation:

Trying to make PK font uvblo at 900 DPI... Running miktex-makemf.exe...

miktex-makemf: The uvblo source file could not be found. Running ttf2pk.exe...

miktex-makepk: PK font uvblo could not be created.

Process exited with error(s)

Then I went to update the packages under MikTeX. Now I get the following:

Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed for the following reason: PK font uvblo could not be created. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:/Users/connolly/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makepk.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

Process exited with error(s)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I know nothing about `uvblo`, but it looks like a non free font. The `.tfm` file is not sufficient, because it only contains the metric information.

Comment: It seems  your template uses Adobe Univers font, and LaTeX does not know how to use it, nor where it is. So the question is: do you have this font installed on your system. If so, did you run `updmap.exe` from the command line?  Also, could we have access to the template?

Comment: The TFM file tells TeX how big each character in the font is, how much space it should leave between words and characters and when to adjust the spacing between particular characters or substitute a third character for two characters in the input. It doesn't contain any information about what the glyphs representing the characters look like. It just treats them as boxes with particular dimensions. The little pictures of the characters - the glyphs - need to be provided, too i.e. you need a `.mf` or `.pfb` or similar, as others have suggested.

Comment: Thanks for all for your helpful comments. The issue pertains to a journal template class file, and I believe it is only needed for the title. @Bernard did you want me to send/upload the file?

Comment: @J. Lars: Yes, or at least a link to download it. Clearly, MiKTeX is trying to make bitmap fonts, and  doesn't find the necessary material to make them. Anyway, as these are type1 (vector) fonts, it even shouldn't try to do that if it were correctly configured.

Comment: @Bernard: The link to the template files are located at [BJPS](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayMoreInfo?jid=JPS&type=ifc).